# Google Sign-In: exchange code for access token and ID token

Tags: google-signin, google-openid

I am using client ID for Android/iOS to authenticate users with Google Sign-In. This is working fine and I receive a code after successful authentication.

Now for some reason I would like to validate this code in the server-side with google and obtain access token. But we do not have any secret key for client ID(s) for Android/iOS. How can I verify the code and get the access token?

Comment: I would recommend you use the https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android SDK. And for getting started see: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2